# Why does MutationObserver fire twice for childList but never for characterData?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I have a simple `MutationObserver` setup as a test. The HTML has a `span` whose text content gets updated once per second (and a `div` for messages):

```
<span class="tester"></span>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

The MutationObserver is set to watch `.tester` and writes text to the `#msg` `div` when it observes a change. Meanwhile, a `setInterval()` runs once/second to change the text in `.tester`:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.tester');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
    $('#msg').append(mutation.type+"<br/>")
    setTimeout(function() { $('#msg').text(''); }, 500);
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(target, config);

setInterval(function() {
  $('#msg').text('');
  $('.tester').text("update: "+Math.random())
}, 1000);
```

I would expect this code to print once per second that the *characterData* has changed. According to [Mozilla's docs for MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), it says about characterData: "Set to true if mutations to target's data are to be observed." Instead, I see no characterData mutations but *do* see two childList mutations every second.

Why am I not seeing any characterData mutations, and why am I seeing *two* childList mutations?

Here's a working example with [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bengrosser/pen/xVKaKx?editors=1010).

Comment: I haven't verified this, but I think that `jQuery().text()`/`.innerText` implicitly removes the existing text node(s) and adds a new one in its place, rather than updating the existing text node. Try manually changing `target.firstChild.nodeValue` and see if it has a different result.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: That's it exactly, you should post an answer demonstrating it (contrasting with modifying `nodeValue` of the existing text node).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried the change to the code: I did stop getting the childList events but didn't start getting the characterData event. :/ I don't have time to figure out why not at the moment. Somebody else can post an answer if they do.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Done. (You have to observe `subtree`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is as [Jeremy Banks said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640501/why-does-mutationobserver-fire-twice-for-childlist-but-never-for-characterdata/35640714#comment58962527_35640501): When you use jQuery's `text()`, it removes all the text nodes and then adds in new ones. That's not a change to character data, it's a change to the `childList`: Removing the node that's there and replacing it with a new one.

To see a change to character data, you have to modify the *existing* text node's `nodeValue`, **and** observe `subtree` modifications:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('.tester');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
        $('#msg').append(mutation.type+"<br/>")
        setTimeout(function() { $('#msg').text(''); }, 500);
    });    
});

var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true                   // <=== Change, added subtree
};
observer.observe(target, config);

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#msg').text('');
    // Change --VVVVV modifying the existing child node
    $('.tester')[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "updated" + Math.random();
}, 1000);

// Stop after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 10000);
```

```html
<span class="tester">x</span><!-- Change, added a starting child node -->
<div id="msg"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Re your question about why there are *two* `childList` mutations, yes I think you're right: They're removing the child, then adding a new one. If we use the [`replaceChild` method](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-785887307), we see only a single mutation:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('.tester');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
        $('#msg').append(mutation.type+"<br/>")
        setTimeout(function() { $('#msg').text(''); }, 500);
    });    
});

var config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true                   // <=== Change, added subtree
};
observer.observe(target, config);

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#msg').text('');
    // Change --VVVVV modifying the existing child node
    var text = document.createTextNode("updated" + Math.random());
    var parent = $('.tester')[0];
    parent.replaceChild(text, parent.firstChild);
}, 1000);

// Stop after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, 10000);
```

```html
<span class="tester">x</span><!-- Change, added a starting child node -->
<div id="msg"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the detail. I composed the example after observing similar mutation behavior on a node that I'm not in control of (watching a website with a userscript), so they must be using a mechanism (like `.text()`) that replaces the data as you describe.

Comment: Still wondering why the `observer` fires twice for childList, though. Is it once for the removal of the existing data and another time for the addition of the new one?

Comment: @mix: That would be my take, yes. Because that is two separate mutations to the childList. Now if they used the [`replaceChild` method](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-785887307), I suspect there'd be only one, but they probably clear and then set.

Comment: @mix: Yup, just added that to the above.

Comment: Trying to test this out, I [forked the codepen](http://codepen.io/bengrosser/pen/NNKLMe?editors=1010) and added the value of the `.tester` text to the message. Unexpectedly, it shows the new text value for both observer events. I was expecting the first line to be blank for the text, the second to have the update.