# How to record text changes in HTML within browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

There is a webpage from which I want to record some text when that text changes.
The text I want to record (indicated by `--->TEXT HERE` in the code below) is dynamically changed in the HTML when the mouse is hovering over an SVG graph.

While I hover the mouse over the SVG graph, I want to store any changed value in those two text nodes and store them into a JavaScript data structure, which I can access later.

I can run additional JavaScript code on the page, but I can't change any of the already existing JavaScript, HTML, or CSS.

The HTML containing the text I want to record looks like this:

```html
[...]
<text x="8" data-z-index="1" style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;cursor:default;fill:#333333;" y="20">
    <span style="font-size: 10px">
    --->TEXT HERE
    </span>
    <span style="fill:#90ed7d" x="8" dy="15">+</span>
    <span dx="0"> Value: </span>
    <span style="font-weight:bold" dx="0">
    --->TEXT HERE
    </span>
</text>
[...]
```

I kind-of snippeted the following code as an example, to make it clearer what I want to do:

```js
// we do not want a blocking browser, so we need some sleep
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// here we are going to save the values from "--->TEXT HERE"
var myvalues = []

async function foo() {
    while(true){
        // Loop until I change the textcontent to "AAA" in the Inspector - stopping with a mouseclick anywhere would be nicer
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('text')[28].childNodes.item(0).textContent == "AAA") 
            break;

        val = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[28].childNodes.item(0).textContent +" "+ document.getElementsByTagName('text')[28].childNodes.item(3).textContent;
        if (!myvalues.includes(val)) 
            myvalues.push(val);

        console.log('Sleep');
        await sleep(100);
    }
}

foo();
```

However, checking for changes periodically doesn't guarantee I will see every change.

How can I record into some JavaScript data structure every change to the text in the areas indicated above by `--->TEXT HERE`?

Comment: @Makyen ,eyllanesc ,M-- Next time please leave a comment and give me a chance to edit my post before closing it. Thank you

Comment: When the text is changed, is *only* the text changed, or are some of the elements replaced (e.g. to change the text, does the current code replace the `<span style="font-size: 10px"></span>` and `<span style="font-weight:bold" dx="0"></span>` (or even more HTML), or does it just change the `.textContent` of those nodes? If it's even more HTML, how much is actually changed? You are currently using `document.getElementsByTagName('text')[28]` to select the `<text>` node. That's a fairly brittle way of selecting it. Is there HTML nearby with a `class` or `id` which could be referenced?

Comment: As to what you want stored, do you definitely want an Array of values which has a single string entry for each change where it is the combination of `--->TEXT HERE --->TEXT HERE` (i.e. the text from both areas concatenated together, but separated by a single space?

Comment: Related, but not duplicates: [MutationObserver on span text change does not trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33521073) and [Why does MutationObserver fire twice for childList but never for characterData?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35640501). Those indicate a common pitfall that is encountered when implementing a `MutationObserver` to watch for the changes to the text within the two `<span>` nodes you are interested in.